# @sendgrid/mail package with Typescript (with noImplicitAny flag set) usage

Tags: typescript, sendgrid

I'm new to Typescript and I'm trying to write a code that will send an email using most recent `@sendgrid/mail` npm package (most responses in SO are regarding "old" `sendgrid` npm package). It already contains some type definitions, however, with `--noImplicitAny` flag set to `true` I'm seeing errors about some sendgrid internal packages (like `@sendgrid/helpers`) having some implicit `any` defined. To me it sounds like type definitions for sendgrid are kinda broken. My question is: what can I do in such case when 3rd party library has some types definitions broken (or with implicit `any` defined) and I want to keep `--noImplicitAny` flag in my `tsconfig.json`? Is there an option to tell compiler to ignore specific 3rd party library errors?

Below is my code:

main.ts (simplified):

```
import sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

sgMail.setApiKey("{ApiKey}");

    let msg = {
        "to": "{recipient}",
        "from": "{sender}",
        "subject": "test",
        "text": "test"
    };

sgMail.send(msg);
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist/",                        
    "strict": true,                           
    "noImplicitAny": true,               
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "main": "main.js",
    "directories": {
        "test": "test"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.1.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "clear && tsc && node dist/main.js"
    }
}
```

Errors that I'm seeing:

`node_modules/@sendgrid/helpers/classes/email-address.d.ts(11,3): error TS7010: 'fromData', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.
node_modules/@sendgrid/helpers/classes/email-address.d.ts(16,3): error TS7010: 'setName', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.
node_modules/@sendgrid/helpers/classes/email-address.d.ts(21,3): error TS7010: 'setEmail', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.`

When I set `--noImplicitAny` to `false` everything works.

Comment: I found another way of solving this issue, namely, instead of `import sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail")`, I'm using `const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail")`. Now, there are no compilation errors, but as far as I understand that way I'm declaring a global variable (it's in my "entry" ts file), that will be available within all files that I will create. If I do `const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail")` in some other file, I will receive errors about `sgMail` variable being already declared.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that the way to solve issues with 3rd party libraries is to set `skipLibCheck` flag in typescript compiler. That way `.d.ts` files won't be checked. The issue is - it will affect all files. there is no simple option if disabling just one `.d.ts` file from checking.

Answer (score 0):

your typescript project should not be scanning your `node_modules` directory for typescript errors. you can set `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` in your `tsconfig.build.json` file to ignore the directory.